# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR removing substring

Tags: regexp-substr

From every String I want to remove the substring "withHugo"

I tried

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('STRING-EXAMPLEwithHugo','(.+)withHugo') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM DUAL;
```

but it returns "STRING-EXAMPLEwithHugo" instead of "STRING-EXAMPLE". How can I REMOVE the 2nd part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want REGEXP_REPLACE here to replace "withHugo" with an empty string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('STRING-EXAMPLEwithHugo','withHugo', '') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" 
FROM DUAL;
```